# How can I know if a virtual package is "installed" on a Debian system?

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, dependencies

Some packages, have a `Provides:` header. For example, the package `postfix` on Debian Wheezy has `Provides: mail-transport-agent`.

The package `mail-transport-agent` which doesn't exist physically is considered as a "virtual" package.

**How can I know, on a Debian based system, if a given virtual package is "installed" (or "provided")? Can I list every "provided" virtual package?**

*Hint*: to list every existing virtual package, installed or not, do: `aptitude search "~v"`

Comment: I don't have a debian at the moment, but wouldn't a dry-run install do the job?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To list packages providing `mail-transport-agent`:

```
$ aptitude search '~Pmail-transport-agent'
p   citadel-mta                     - complete and feature-rich groupware server
p   courier-mta                     - Courier mail server - ESMTP daemon        
p   dma                             - lightweight mail transport agent          
p   esmtp-run                       - user configurable relay-only MTA - the reg
p   exim4-daemon-heavy              - Exim MTA (v4) daemon with extended feature
p   exim4-daemon-light              - lightweight Exim MTA (v4) daemon          
p   masqmail                        - mail transport agent for intermittently co
p   msmtp-mta                       - light SMTP client with support for server 
p   nullmailer                      - simple relay-only mail transport agent    
i   postfix                         - High-performance mail transport agent     
p   sendmail-bin                    - powerful, efficient, and scalable Mail Tra
p   ssmtp                           - extremely simple MTA to get mail off the s
p   xmail                           - advanced, fast and reliable ESMTP/POP3 mai
```

Make that `aptitude search '~Pmail-transport-agent ~i'` to only list installed packages (if any).

To list all virtual packages provided by currently installed packages:

```
aptitude search '~Rprovides:~i ~v'
```

See the [aptitude manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) for an explanation of the search patterns.

Comment: Accepting this answer because is uses standard `aptitude`. I like the explaination of @umläute though.

Comment: On Debian Jessie, I just tried `aptitude search '~Pmysql-server ~i'` which gives `mariadb-server-10.0` and `mariadb-server-core-10.0`, but when I do `aptitude search '~Rprovides:~i ~v'`, I do not see `mysql-server` in the list... However, I do see `virtual-mysql-client`, `virtual-mysql-client-core`, `virtual-mysql-server` and `virtual-mysql-client-core` in the list.

Comment: @figtrap It's faster, sure, [but it doesn't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96309/how-can-i-know-if-a-virtual-package-is-installed-on-a-debian-system/96399?noredirect=1#comment146232_96454).

Comment: That is so useful, do you know how to do this on other package managers? (BTW your link is now 404)

Comment: @user1133275 I don't know how to do it with `apt-cache` or `apt`.

Answer (score 12):

the problem here is that there is a subtle difference between *virtual* packages and packages *provided* by other packages.

the difference is, that a package may *provide* a *real* package as well, not only a *virtual* package.

anyhow, the following will search for all packages that *provide* a package and will print both the package name and the packages it provides:

```
grep-available -sPackage  -sProvides -FProvides -e '^.'
```

to find whether any package is installed on your system that provides a given one (e.g. mail-transport-agent), use

```
grep-status -sPackage -sProvides -FProvides "mail-transport-agent"
```

Comment: Note: the commands `grep-available` and `grep-status` are available once you installed the `dctrl-tools`  package.

Comment: This does not really work, eg: `grep-available -sPackage -FProvides 'mail-transport-agent' ` fails to show anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect the presence of a given virtual package by using `apt-cache showpkg <virtual>` to display a list of candidate packages, and then `dpkg -l <canddate> <candidate> ...` to display the installation status of the candidates.

For example:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg awk
$ dpkg -l original-awk mawk gawk
```

Here is a full printout:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg awk
Package: awk
Versions: 

Reverse Depends: 
  base-files,awk
  base-files,awk
Dependencies: 
Provides: 
Reverse Provides: 
mawk:i386 1.3.3-17ubuntu2
gawk:i386 1:4.0.1+dfsg-2.1ubuntu2
original-awk 2012-12-20-1
mawk 1.3.3-17ubuntu2
gawk 1:4.0.1+dfsg-2.1ubuntu2

$ dpkg -l original-awk mawk gawk
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  gawk           1:4.0.1+dfsg amd64        GNU awk, a pattern scanning and p
ii  mawk           1.3.3-17ubun amd64        a pattern scanning and text proce
dpkg-query: no packages found matching original-awk
```

I believe `dpkg` and `apt-cache` are lower level tools than `aptitude`, `grep-available` and `grep-status`.  Using lower level tools may or may not be a benefit, depending upon your particular requirements.

Comment: That did not work for me in the case a virtual package has replaced a real package. `apt-cache search package` listed the real and virtual package provider.

Answer (score -1):

You can get all of the virtual packages from the [AUTHORITATIVE LIST OF VIRTUAL PACKAGE NAMES](http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/virtual-package-names-list.txt). As for determining if a virtual package is installed I use `dpkg -l` and the fact that it has an exit code of 0 if the package is installed and an exit code of 1 if it is not installed.

```
dpkg -l mail-transport-agent &> /dev/null; echo $?
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. `dpkg -l mail-transport-agent` can return 0 even if there is no package providing it that is currently installed. I think it's based on presence in `/var/dpkg/lib/available` but I'm not sure. I did check that `dpkg -l foo` returns 1 for a package that I've never installed but 0 for a package that I just purged.

Comment: Your Link id 404.