# How can I locate a specific kernel source code on my machine

Tags: kernel

I want to locate the kernel's `signal.c` source code on my machine, to study the differences (if exist) between what I have and [this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/signal.c) source code.
I tried following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159833/how-do-i-get-the-kernel-source-code) post suggestion, but didn't get far.

I guess I need more specific instructions. I'm working with ubuntu 14.04, x86_64, linux-source-3.13.0 (last one is an output from `apt-cache search linux-source`).

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the instructions, you have installed a kernel source package, named **`linux-source-3.13.0`**, e.g., by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source-3.13.0
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

which installs a [virtual package](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_system_administration/debian_linux_guides/debian_linux_faq/ch-pkg_basics.en_007.html) that installs the *versioned* package as a dependency.

Having done that, you can find the file you were looking for (using the package name):

```
dpkg -L linux-source-3.13.0 |grep -F signal.c
```

and get the pathname(s) of any files in that package named "signal.c"

If the package was actually a tarball of the sources, you would have to extract those files, e.g., using `tar`.  In that case, `dpkg -L linux-source` would only list the tarball (and the grep would return nothing).

For the case of a tarball, you could do this:

```
tar tvf $(dpkg -L linux-source-3.13.0) |grep -F signal.c
```

if it contained only one file.  But supposing you had something like

```
/usr
/usr/src
/usr/src/linux-patch-3.13-rt.patch.bz2
/usr/src/linux-source-3.13.tar.bz2
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-3.13
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-3.13/copyright
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-3.13/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/linux-source-3.13/README.Debian
```

then the file you are looking for would be in the "tar.bz2" file, so...

```
tar tvf $(dpkg -L linux-source-3.13.0|grep -F .tar.bz2) |grep -F signal.c
```

would show the pathnames within that tarball for "signal.c"

Further reading:

- [How can I know if a virtual package is “installed” on a Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96309/how-can-i-know-if-a-virtual-package-is-installed-on-a-debian-system)
- [BuildYourOwnKernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) (Ubuntu wiki)
- [Package linux-source](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source) (Ubuntu)

Comment: Am I supposed to replace `linux-source` with something else? I get the output: `package 'linux-source' is not installed`. I tried replacing it with `linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic`, without results.

Comment: How can I determine if the package need to be extracted?

Comment: I'd start with "dpkg -L linux-source |less" and see what it has in it.

Comment: Once again, I got: `dpkg-query: package 'linux-source' is not installed`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for this command: `sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Even with Debian, it's possible that the running kernel does not match the latest source.  However, if OP recalls which package they installed, they can look at its contents.

Comment: |1.| @ThomasDickey, I didn't use `sudo apt-get install linux-source-3.13.0`. If I would, will it reinstall the current Kernel? I don't want that.
  
|2.| @ChefPharaoh, I executed what you suggested. What should I do next? `dpkg -L linux-source` still results in the above message.
I did, however, tried `dpkg -L linux-image-$(uname -r)`, and the output looks similiar to @ThomasDickey's output, but with no `.bz2` files.
  
|3.| In examining the output of ``sudo apt-get install linux-source-3.13.0`, I do see this: `linux-lts-vivid-3.19.0/kernel/signal.c`. But I can't find it on my pc.

Comment: @HelterSkelter The package `linux-source...` provides the source files; `linux-image...` provides the kernel.  Did you run `apt-get install linux-source-...`?  Your comment says that |1.| you didn't, and |3.| you did (and examined the output).

Comment: @JigglyNaga, sorry, my |3.| is wrong; It should be: "in examining the output of  `sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` "

Comment: Update: Now I did executed `sudo apt-get install linux-source-3.13.0`, and then tried `dpkg -L linux-source`, and again got the message: `package 'linux-source' is not installed`.

Comment: That's expected: you installed the version-specific package, which doesn't pull in the (redundant) virtual package.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, so what else can I try?